# Filter lines containing date between a range in csv file in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I am new in c# and also working with csv files. I need to filter csv file using a range of dates.

The content of the csv file are like the data below.

"EmployeeCode","Date","Time","Type"
"3434","01/22/2013","07:54","0"
"3023","01/23/2014","07:54","0"
"2897","01/24/2015","07:54","0"
"3734","01/25/2015","07:54","0"
"3168","01/26/2015","07:54","0"
"4863","01/26/2015","07:55","0"
"2513","01/27/2015","07:55","0"
"2582","01/27/2015","07:55","0"

THIS SHOULD BE THE OUTPUT:

"EmployeeCode","Date","Time","Type"
"3734","01/25/2015","07:54","0"
"3168","01/26/2015","07:54","0"
"4863","01/26/2015","07:55","0"
"2513","01/27/2015","07:55","0"
"2582","01/27/2015","07:55","0"

Shell can do this, its unfair that c# can't. Because after searching this kind of problem to internet, no found solution.

Trying this code.

```
 DateTime dFm = new DateTime(2015, 01, 25);
 DateTime dTo = new DateTime(2015, 01, 27);

 var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtFileName.Text); 
 var data = lines
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                EmpCode = Int32.Parse(x.Split(new string[] { @""",""", @"""" 
             }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]),
                Date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                string.Concat(x.Split(new string[] { @""",""", @"""" }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1], " ",
                x.Split(new string[] { @""",""", @"""" }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]),
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Type = x.Split(new string[] { @""",""", @"""" }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[3]
            })
            .Where(x => x.Date >= dFm && x.Date <= dTo)
            .ToList();
           }
```

Comment: How did you figure that C# can't? What code did you try writing?

Comment: C# can, you can't :)

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonably easy to achieve your goal with [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/):

```
var dFm = new DateTime(2015, 01, 25);
var dTo = new DateTime(2015, 01, 27);
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"sample.csv"))
{
    var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var date = csv.GetField<DateTime>("Date");
        if (date >= dFm &&
            date <= dTo)
        {
            // process the filtered out records
        }
    }
}
```

In the example I stored your data in the sample.csv file. Also, on my machine I use European date convention (day/month/year) and had to adjusted the data. I assume it will be fine on your machine if it's set up to American convention (month/day/year).

In the `process the filtered out records` you add your logic to write the records to your preferred output (I've left it unimplemented as didn't want to spoil all fun).

As mentioned at the beginning I use CsvHelper. I wouldn't risk implementing CSV parser on your own - it's a complex and time consuming task and there is already an excellent library out there.

Comment: First line of my answer is the link. It will take you to the project's website where you can find all the fine details of the library.

Comment: can you supply if statement for me?just to make this my example.

Comment: You mean this if statement: `if (date >= dFm && date <= dTo)`?

Comment: Yeah.like to write into a file  those line within the range.